# Simple str_replace() making things wrong - WordPress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, replace, add-filter

I need some special filtering to certain text all over my website, like below:

```
function special_text( $content ) {
    $search_for = 'specialtext';
    $replace_with = '<span class="special-text"><strong>special</strong>text</span>';
    return str_replace( $search_for, $replace_with, $content );
}    
add_filter('the_content', 'special_text', 99);
```

It's doing thing in an excellent way, BUT...

in content if there's any link like: `<a title="specialtext" href="http://specialtext.com">specialtext</a>` then the title and href texts also changed and the link becomes broken.

**How can I make exception there?**

Is there a way I can put some exceptions in an array and `str_replace()` simply skip 'em?

Comment: You might consider using a [DOM parser](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=php+dom+parser) for something like this.

Comment: is "specialtext" being wrapped in anything else? Or is it just that text string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use regular expression and use function `preg_replace()` to replace matched string. Here is the full implementation of your `special_text()` function.

```
function special_text( $content ) {
    $search_for = 'specialtext';
    $replace_with = '<span class="special-text"><strong>special</strong>text</span>';
    return preg_replace( '/<a.*?>(*SKIP)(*F)|'.$search_for.'/m', $replace_with, $content );
}
```

In the following regular expression first, using `<a.*?>` - everything between `<a...>` is matched and using `(*SKIP)(*F)|` it is skipped and then from anything else `$search_for` is matched (in your case it's `specialtext`).

Comment: I might not be testing it correctly, but this doesn't seem to replace the `specialtext` between the `a` tags. OP seemingly only wants the text preserved if it is part of a tag attribute. Tested [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d765cf463617549493fb2a278f09e197df5a110b).

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQ I've misread this part. Now it should work fine.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek: Thank you. But I forgot to mention that, my project folder is also with such a name of my text i.e. `specialtext`. So the absolute path contains the string too. And it's not skipping the `<img src="">` so the images are broken. :( - (But for anchor tags it's working just fine.)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam is it strictly connected to this issue? If so, please add details, if not, you should simply create one more question with current state and mentioning what should be changed

Answer (score 1):

Jezzabeanz quite got it except you can simplify it still with:

```
return preg_replace("/^def/", $replace_with, $content);
```

Comment: Very true, nice one Farid.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text between the the **a** tags then a regular expression works wonders.

Here is something I used when I was pulling data from emails sent to me:

```
(?<=">)(.*?\w)(?=<\/a)
```

returns "specialtext"

It also returns "specialtext test" if there is whitespace.

Regular expressions are definitely the way to go.

```
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

And then do a replace on the returned matches.

Comment: See some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/) for reference as to why regex is _rarely_ what you want to use for parsing HTML.

Comment: "it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML."
If Mayeenul is only replacing the text between hyperlinks then this falls under the band of "limited, known set...".

Comment: Yes, but without that being explicitly stated as what's wanted, I don't think it is a safe assumption. Especially given "... all over my website ..."

Comment: Yes very true, I was taking his example literally. The regex example I gave was limited, true, but he can certainly do what he needs to do with a regular expression. 

If he want's something a little more comprehensive then he's better off using the DOM Parser as you suggested in the comment you gave on the OP.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz it won't work if `$search_for = 'specialtext';` There is no info in OP question that only text inside a has to be changed.